# Ubuntu 18.04 no sound on imac mid-2017 21,5"

Tags: 18.04, sound, alsa, mac

A fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04 provides no sound out-of-the-box on an iMac mid-2017 with 21,5 inch 4K Retina display.
Specs of the iMac:

- Intel core i5-7500
- 8GB RAM
- Radeon Pro 560
- 1TB Fusion drive

The macOS was complete unmodified (*vanilla*). I updated macOS to the version 10.14 "Mojave" to be sure that the latest firmware is installed.
Then I installed Ubuntu 18.04 from an usb stick, **WITHOUT USING BOOT CAMP**.

The installation run really fine and everything worked out-of-the-box, but no sound at all from the integrated speakers.

```
alsamixer
```

shows a Cirrus Logic controller and only one PCM output channel, nothing else.
According to [the teardown of iFixit](https://de.ifixit.com/Teardown/iMac%2BIntel%2B21.5-Inch%2BRetina%2B4K%2BDisplay%2B2017%2BTeardown/92170#s172311) the audio controller is a Cirrus Logic CS42L83, which seems to be pretty new in the imac mid-2017.

I've already tried everything from the internet by configuring the file /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and trying different chip models but nothing helps.

It seems that all workarounds and sound issue fixings for imacs older than mid-2017 do not apply anymore for this model.

*Has anyone an idea or an experience to share on how to solve this problem?*

EDIT:

ok, it seems that the linux kernel can not manage to control the sound card of the imac mid-2017.
The imac mid-2017 has the same sound controller Cirrus Logic CS42L83 as the 2016 and 2017 MacBook.
Progress about support can be followed at [GitHub](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux)

Comment: Did your issue get resolved? I have a MacBook Pro Mid 2017 im thinking of installing Ubuntu

Comment: @ JcbJoe: no, I never get the problem solved. I've sold the iMac about one year ago. Everything was fine except the sound card which has never worked.